# Shell.Application: How to copy files

Tags: shell, asp-classic

I am writing an ASP file to copy file from one folder to another:

```
<%
set shell1=server.createobject("shell.application")
%>
```

I would like to know how I can copy file from `D:\from\from.txt` to `D:\to\`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the CopyFile method on the FileSystemObject.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w(v=VS.85).aspx